# printing variable out of scope does not yield error

Tags: dart, types, scope

I had this weird problem in Dart. Consider the following code :

```
class Number {
  int num = 10;
}
```

Here, I created a little class with a `int` object `num`
When I try to print it using the `main()` function *OUTSIDE* the class like :

```
main() {
   print(num);
}
```

I get the output as :
`num`
Which is weird, since I expected an error. If I were to print a undefined variable as in `print(foo);` I would get an error, which is expected.
What I find even more interesting is the `runtimeType` of a variable whose value is `num`.

```
  var temp = num;
  print(temp.runtimeType);
}
```

The above code prints `_Type`, when I expected it to be `int`.
Can somebody please clear this?

Answer (score 3):

The name `num` is a [type](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/num-class.html) declared in `dart:core`. It's the supertype of `int` and `double`.

When you do `print(num);` outside the scope where your `int num;` variable is declared, the `num` refers to that type from `dart:core` which is always imported and therefore in scope.
Dart type names can be used as expressions, they evaluate to a [`Type`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Type-class.html) object.

So, you are printing a `Type` object for the type `num`, which prints "num", and the run-time type of that object, which is again a `Type` object, which prints `_Type` because that's the actual internal type of the `Type` object instance.